# HTML pattern attribute for space and list of words

Tags: regex, html, forms, web

I am working on validating user input in a html form. I want the form to catch any blank spaces and a list of words not permitted.

```
<td><input type="text" name="Name" pattern="^[^\s]+$|cow|horse" required ></td>
```

The bit of pattern value "^[^\s]+$" seems to catch if any white spaces are in the input. However the following code does not catch/stop the form submission if cow or horse is entered. Can someone advice me on this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could validate with Javascript like this:

```
<form name="testform" action="testpage.php" onsubmit="return validate()" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Name" pattern="^[^\s]+$" required>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
    function validate() {
        var x = document.forms["testform"]["Name"].value;
        if (x == "cow" || x == "horse") {
            alert("can not be "+x);
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/y9mperc0/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried it out and it works fine :) I really wanted to avoid any script and just do all in html. But the fact is I do have a long list of words, so maybe a clean script to handle them at the end would be good. Thanks again. If you do know a solution using HTML that will be good to know for further references. Thanks.

Comment: if you've got a long list it might also be best to store them in an array like this: http://jsfiddle.net/y9mperc0/1/

Comment: Thanks mate. Just what I was after to implement. Looks like Javascript approach would be a clean one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assert that the input field:

- Does not contain any whitespace character (as defined by `\s`, which is equivalent to `[ \f\n\r\t\v​\u00a0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​-\u200a​\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f​\u3000\ufeff]`)
- Is not an empty string
- Is not equal to `cow` or `horse`

Then you can use the following regex:

```
^(?!(cow|horse)$)\S+$
```

Since `pattern` field of `input` tag validates that the **whole string** matches the pattern, the `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end are redundant.

```html
<input type="text" name="Name" pattern="(?!(cow|horse)$)\S+" required>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This is the right answer for the question. This answer is exactly the way I wanted to solve my question. But since I have already accepted the javascript solution, I cannot mark this as an answer. Thanks for answering as it will help with future refecences and help others with simialr question.

Comment: I have a long list of words, for which I want input assert, therefore the javascript soluton might be more suitable for my task.

Answer (score 0):

This is for boundary substrings (words) -

`^(?:(?!\s|\b(?:cow|horse)\b)[\S\s])+$`

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      (?!
           \s 
        |  
           \b 
           (?: cow | horse )
           \b 
      )
      [\S\s] 
 )+
 $
```

This is for non- boundary substrings -

`^(?:(?!\s|cow|horse)[\S\s])+$`

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      (?!
           \s 
        |  cow
        |  horse
      )
      [\S\s] 
 )+
 $
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: @Saed - Any details or reason ? Your words `if cow or horse is entered`. This matches _cow_ or _horse_, so you got it wrong, not me..

Comment: my apologies if the question wasn't clear enough. Like I mentioned in the question: " However the following code does not catch/stop the form submission if cow or horse is entered.", I wanted the form submission to be stopped if cow or horse was entered. The form submission just went through without any invalid notification. thanks.

Comment: @Saed - Then its not the regex. The above regex won't match `cow` _or_ `horse` _or_ `whitespace` anywhere in the string. That's all it does. It's more than likely the regex is not invoked at all. You have some sort of forms problem.